# Jprofiler 9 throwing segemnetation fault in offline mode

Tags: java, performance, jvm, segmentation-fault, jprofiler

I have installed jprofiler 9 on windows 7, i am trying  to remote profile a JVM running on remote linux in offline mode.

I have added the JVM arguments in the JVM arguments as follows. and copied the binaries and the config.xml into the linux box.

```
#Jprofiler Settings
JAVA_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jprofilerti=port=8849,nowait -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/jprofiler9/bin/agent.jar -agentpath:/home/jprofiler9/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=offline,id=108,config=/home/.jprofiler9/config.xml  ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
export JAVA_OPTIONS
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jprofiler9/bin/linux-x64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now when i start the server i get a segmentation fault and it dumps core, out logs are below

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 50
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Starting up without initial configuration.
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> Protocol version 50
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> Offline profiling mode.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Using config file /home/.jprofiler9/config.xml (id: 108)
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Using sampling (1 ms)
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
**JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled**
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Using sampling (1 ms)
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
<PATH>/startWebLogic.sh: line 192:  3372 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WLS_POLICY_FILE} ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}
Stopping Derby server...
```

1) In online mode using GUI , server starts and i can take profiles. However while the server is starting i detach the Jprofiler from the server and once the server has started i attach again and take profiles. 
So in offline mode is there a detach and attach function?

Note the server starting heap size is 8GB

2) so in the offline mode is the server actually trying to capture CPU profile , because in logs it says **"JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled"**  . can this be a reason as to why the server start is failing with the segmentation Error

Thanks

Comment: Is there an hserr_pid... file in the working directory of the profiled JVM?

Comment: no thee is no hserr_pid file , gdb of the core dump shows this. this comes while the server is starting 

`Core was generated by /home/jdk/bin/java -server -Xms768m -Xmx1536m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:M'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f4d7ed8a9f0 in ?? ()
"/home/core.PID" is a core file.
Please specify an executable to debug.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f4d7ed8a9f0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f4d7ed8aa1b in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)`

Answer (score 0):

You load the native agent library twice. This means that you pass two -agentlib:jprofilerti parameters or another -agentpath parameter that loads the agent library.